# Domain and target space of a transformation

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Assume we have a matrix

$$A = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 \\ \end{pmatrix} $$

and a vector $x$

$$x = \begin{pmatrix} x_1 \\ x_2 \end{pmatrix} $$

And a transformation $T_A$ is defined as $T_A(x)=Ax$

The first task is to find the domain and target space of the transformation.

By the rules of matrix-vector multiplication, 
$$ Ax = \begin{pmatrix} x_1 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix} $$

Does it mean that the domain is $\mathbb R^2$ by the number of columns in A, but the target space is $\mathbb R^1$ as we've got only $x_1$ in the end?

Comment: Presumably the domain is $\mathbb{R}^2$ (the domain is usually specified), the range is the set of vectors $\{ \binom{t}{0} \}_{t \in \mathbb{R}}$. It 'looks' like $\mathbb{R}$ but it is a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^2$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The domain is $\mathbb{R}^2 $ because are considering $T$ as

$$T:\mathbb{R}^2\rightarrow  \mathbb{R}^2$$

But the transformation is not surjective, and you can produce the range of $T$ with $$  \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix} $$

So the range is one dimensional, that is $\mathbb{R}^1.$